# Adding keyframes while modifiers are active

Tags: keyframes, graph-editor

I've come to learn that if you disable all f-curves *Modifiers on an active bone, you can insert new keyframes for that bone by moving things in the pose editor. Once you reapply the f-curve modifiers by clicking the checkmark box in the top right corner of the modifier window for each f-curve, both the f-curve modifiers and keyframe movements are preserved.

My question is, is there either:
a. a way to insert new keyframes while an f-curve modifier is active
b. a way to uncheck f-curve modifiers in bulk (for animations that have many modifiers applied)

And I know that you can just click the wrench icon in the left pane, but that doesn't work the same as disabling each of the f-curve modifiers manually. Also, why is this the case? Is there some alternative purpose that I don't know about? Or is it just a bug or currently unimplemented feature?

Comment: Uhh, you can keyframe modified f-curves.  Those keyframes don't necessarily *do* anything, depending on whether the modifiers replace the f-curve vs are specified as additive.  Maybe you can share a file where you can't keyframe modified f-curves?

Comment: I can't seem to keyframe while modifiers are active at all... I always get the error

"F-Curve cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers"

Comment: Like I said, maybe you can share a file?  I tested creating fcurve modifiers in 2.91.0, but there may be special circumstances for you.

Comment: Sure, I'll upload an example of what I mean

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtmwzK4EJ_YdKz-uIqG0YmcFMTpFhEWt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In that file that I sent to my google drive, you can see that sinusoidal modifiers are applied to the x,y,z positions. Unless you uncheck each of those modifiers manually, it keeps sending the message "F-Curve cannot be keyframed, ensure that it is not locked or sampled, and try removing F-Modifiers"

Comment: What I do is, set the influence to 10^-3, and the amplitude to 10^3 of what value I want it at so that the keyframe affects the trajectory of the modifier.
This is the example of a desired effect where keyframes and f-curves work together:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/195Mf6-_X5nU4qS4re4c3pBb6r_LBvZUX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set keyframes, enable "additive" on the modifier settings of any channels you wish to keyframe, then keyframe them.  (This will require expanding the f-curve modifiers so you can see their options.)  If you'd like to disable "additive" afterwards, you can, and the keyframes will remain, but keep in mind that keyframes don't actually affect the output of modified f-curves unless "additive" is set-- otherwise, the modifier straight up *replaces* the keyframed values.

Comment: Thank you! I think this solved my problem :)